# Как лучше реализовать удаление записей?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

yii2, имеется запись пользователя в таблице user и записи складов в таблице storage.

к нему (через actioUpdate), путем выделения чекбоксов, привязываю склады создавая записи с user_id и storage_id в смежной таблице many-to-many.

при следующем редактировании записи пользователя через js отмечаются чекбоксы с нужным storage_id, которые связаны с user_id.

необходимо при снятии выбора с чекбокса и последующего сохранения записи удалять деактивированную запись в смежной таблице.

сейчас делается так: при каждом сохранении записи удаляю все записи с такими storage_id, которые не были переданы в экшене.

но это , имхо, не правильно.

вопрос: как это можно реализовать лучше и правильнее ? с точки зрения производительности. просто дергать каждый раз эту таблицу, имхо, не очень оптимально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути есть два варианта:

1. При сохранении из смежной таблицы удаляем все строки с `user_id`. И заного туда добавляем. Получается мы из смежной таблицы удалили все связи с пользователем и заново добавили.
2. Второй вариант это сравнение. Допустим при сохранении мы получили id's - 1, 3, 6.
   Делаем запрос к базе по `user_id`. Например там 2, 3, 7, 8. Теперь сравниваем иды. Если в старом списке есть иды, а новом нет, то удаляем их по `storage_id`. Если в старом списке нет идов, а в новом есть, то добавляем их.

По мне так первый вариант должен вам подойти.

Comment: я думал над первым вариантом и реализовал второй (в вопросе: `сейчас делается так: при каждом сохранении записи удаляю все записи с такими storage_id, которые не были переданы в экшене.`). а потом мне подсказали не удалять записи, а помечать их удаленными, и я решил реализовать именно такую систему. но спасибо, что подтвердили, что так тоже делается.